# How do I correct permissions for the command locate?

Tags: permissions, locate

I used to use the command 'locate' for some 15 years now, with daily 'sudo updatedb'.
Strange enough, since the most recent upgrade of Ubuntu, it doesn't give me results, but asks for the root password.
I do understand that in some cases this is a good thing, but for my case here I'd rather go back to the old way. Have tried to find a solution online, but couldn't.
What has been changed?

Comment: At some point, the default implementation was changed from mlocate to plocate - but that should not have caused the issue you are describing. What exactly is "the most recent upgrade"? What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what implementation of `locate` (`locate --version`)? what is the output of `ls -l $(realpath /usr/bin/locate)` ?

Comment: The most recent upgrade was Kubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.1.
The version is plocate 1.1.15.
The executable is -rwxr-sr-x 1 root plocate 313904 Feb 17  2022 /usr/bin/plocate.